# Update progress position?

Tags: css, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

My update progress displays under the update panel. Is there a way to display it near the control which caused the async postback? I have a very long form so users might not scroll all the way down and see the progress at all.

### Edit

I am using a table for my layout inside the update panel. The update progress is placed right after the table. It seems it always displays after the table.

Is there a way in CSS to show the update progress div on the top right of screen according to current scroll position ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
#div_update { position:fixed; top:0; right:0; }
```

It would place your  at the top right corner of the screen, don't care about the current scroll.